# Why do I have a question mark instead of a material design icon in my iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator

I want to use a material design icon in my Flutter app. But I get a strange behaviour of my iOs simulator - I have a question mark in a square instead of the icon. In Android emulator the icon looks fine.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should check your pubspec.yaml file:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

If contains this line. The icons are from material design, if without this line, these icons are all replaced by a question mark icon.

Answer (score 0):

Material icons are implemented and supported by Google and can be easily displayed on emulators and Android phones, but in some cases they do not work properly on iOS.
You have two solutions to this problem:

1. Use the [font_wesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter) library, which contains both material icons and many more icons.
2. The second solution is to use coprinto instead of ingredients in different parts of the program
   I hope I have fully explained